# Playing OGG File Outside of HTTDOCS

Tags: php, html, apache

I am trying to play an OGG file with the HTML5 video tag; the file is located outside of httdocs since you have to pay to view it.

The web page that plays that file is in this directory:
/home/admin/public_html/video/

Inside this folder I created a php file (srv.php):

```
header("Content-type: application/ogg");
readfile("/home/admin/videos/".$_GET['src']);
exit();
```

Then to play the file I would use:

```
<video width="400" height="400" controls>
<source src="srv.php?src=<NAME>">
```

This let's me keep the ogg file outside httdocs.

The problem is I can just go to this URL:

```
 <MY SITE>.com/video/srv.php?src=<NAME>
```

and view the video.

If I move srv.php outside of HTTDOCS the video does not play; get a location not found error.

Is there any way for me move srv.php outside of HTTDOCS and still let the video be played?

Comment: Surely you can just use `srv.php` to either provide access to the file or not, based on the users account?

Comment: That's exactly what I did; figure it out right after I wrote the question. I should have deleted but forgot to. Thanks for responding.